# on tap of minicontroller is not taking to extended controller in android chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

why minicontroller is not taking to extended controller on Tap of it. 
 I added the below code for minicontroller as given in [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#6)

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
            class="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

But on in my case the minicontroller's progress bar is not on bottom, it's coming on top of minicontroller block.

And on tapping it it is not taking to Extended controller activity why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must refer [notification and lockscreen](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#7) part of codelabs.

check have you registered `NotificationOptions` are not. That part will do your work

```
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.CastMediaOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.NotificationOptions;

public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
    NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
            .setTargetActivityClassName(VideoBrowserActivity.class.getName())
            .build();
    CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
            .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
            .build();

    return new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
            .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
            .build();
}
```